# How to make a variable retain its value after reloading, in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, variables, select, global

An event is something that happens like pressing a button in a web page which causes it to reload. Thus, my variables have reset. How do I retain its value?

**More detail:**

I want to create a simple product catalog with various categories *and* sub-categories in a single web page that enables filter, so I am using PHP.

Each category has a button on the page, and clicking that button will show the sub-category buttons; and by clicking the sub-category button will show the products.

But the problem is, clicking the a button resets the variable of the selected category which messes up my select function that shows the products. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this: (1) a session, and (2) a form.

A session is used to store values between page requests - it uses a cookie to identify your browser, which PHP manages for you. Your category could be set into a variable, and then re-read at page load.

The other approach is to wrap both your category and sub-category controls in a form. Clicking submit will send both of these values to the server. When you are setting just the category, you'll not have a sub-category; the server should reply with the same category and a menu for subcategories. If you re-render the category menu (even though it is already set), resubmitting the form will ensure the category is not lost.

Out of the two of these, I'd probably do the second one.